# How to implement dynamic datasets in a SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the following scenario: a single .rdl file with a stored procedure as datasource. This stored procedure accepts two parameters: `@ProcedureName nvarchar(max)` and `@Parameters xml`. The functionality of the stored procedure is to call another stored procedure (most probably on a different database) with the given XML parameters. So, in essence, each of the stored procs that gets executed will return it's own dataset.

How would I go about creating a tablix/matrix that consumes the dataset without specifying the columns as the columns need to get generated at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SSRS doesn't have "AutoGenerateColumns"-style functionality and resolves a number of things at design time.  So the short answer is that you cannot.

The designer checks field references when saving, and will not save with a reference to a field that isn't in a dataset's field list.  If a field ceases to exist after the report definition is generated, it will show up as a static blank value on the report.  Expressions will do so as well, even if the field is in an unevaluated portion.  So if field B is removed, this expression would still be affected:

`=IIF(1=1,Fields!A.Value,Fields!B.Value)`

Which means that you can't use conditional grouping expressions as a workaround, even if you had an exhaustive list of the columns that might be returned.

Comment: I ended up generating the XML markup for the RDL file dynamically with accompanying XSLT transformation for the different datasets. So based on the dataset returned, I managed to create the relevant tablix structure. However, getting the XML formatting correct is a bit of a hassle since I need to create the RDL file beforehand to see what the markup looked like (grouping, special expressions, etc.)